# Rich notification images not showing for second notification

Tags: objective-c, ios10

Scheduling 2 local notification at the same time with UNNotificationAttachment image.  If I clear fired first notification from mobile notification tray, So for second rich notification not showing attached image.

## Here is my code:-

```
- (void)scheduleNotification1 {

    UNMutableNotificationContent *notificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    notificationContent.body = @"Reminder 1 Notification";
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = @"Reminder 1";

    notificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        notificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]);
    NSString *imageURLString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bird" ofType:@"jpeg"];
    UNNotificationAttachment *imageAttachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"Reminder 1" URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageURLString] options:nil error:nil];
    notificationContent.attachments = @[imageAttachment];

    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:10
                                                                                                    repeats:NO];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"Reminder 1"
                                                   content:notificationContent
                                                   trigger:trigger];

    /// 3. schedule localNotification
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = (id)((AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
    [center addNotificationRequest:request
             withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error-- ");
                 }

             }];

    [self scheduleNotification2];

}

- (void)scheduleNotification2 {

    UNMutableNotificationContent *notificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    notificationContent.body = @"Reminder 2 Notification";
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = @"Reminder 2";
    notificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    notificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]);
    NSString *imageURLString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bird1" ofType:@"jpeg"];
    UNNotificationAttachment *imageAttachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"Reminder 2" URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageURLString] options:nil error:nil];
    notificationContent.attachments = @[imageAttachment];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = nil;
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:15
                                                                                                    repeats:NO];
    request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"Reminder 2"
                                                   content:notificationContent
                                                   trigger:trigger];
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = (id)((AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
    [center addNotificationRequest:request
             withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error-- ");
                 }

             }];
}
```

=============

Please let me know why it is not showing image for 2nd rich notification?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes, I was using the single image for both notifications. 
So I used different images and it's solved my problem.

Comment: In my case, I'm using 2 different images for 2 notifications but it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: UPD: I've solved this problem by generating unique identifier for each attachment, using `UUID().uuidString`

Comment: Yes, Attachments should be unique. Thanks @AndyC